# Changing _ReadBatchSize and -LoginTimeout parameters on Log Reader profile

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to change the above parameters on a profile specifically set up for the log reader on a SQL Server 2008 transactional replication publication, but cannot find where to do this.  Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS go to:

Replication -> (Right Click) Distributor Properties -> General -> Profile Defaults -> Log Reader Agents -> Default agent profile

Answer (score 0):

Soon after posting, I found clear instructions on how to do this from Microsoft here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147893.aspx

Sorry about that.  Honestly, I looked for hours before posting this question.